# Unity online hosted AssetBundles and Appstore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, app-store

This is my first project working with Unity AssetBundles, I've made a system so that the only thing I have in my package are Unity scenes, so I can disable them in the build settings and unity won't build all of their dependencies. I'm hosting and downloading my bundle from my own website domain, so my question is if this is okay with the app store policies and if an app can get approved when using AssetBundles this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your app should be able to get approved if you use Assetbundles (Assuming you comform to the app stores [policies](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)), in fact it is pretty much what they are made to do (download content such as scenes), textures and models after installation).

The only limitation is the one that is already in-place in Unity, and that is that you cannot download/implement new *scripts* using assetbundles (and are not allowed to download new scripts through any other means). But if you stick to scenes/assets you're fine.

If you want to download scripts through assetbundles though, you can use Reflection for this on android, Though this is not an option on iOS as that is AOT compiled (Ahead of time).